# Trigger pipeline on completion of multiple pipelines yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I have two different pipelines A and B and need to trigger pipeline C on completion of pipeline A or pipeline B.Please A and B runs individually so wherenver the pipeline completes it should trigger pipeline C

I thought trigger in pipeline C should work, but it doesn't trigger

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: A
      source: A.source
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master
    - pipeline: B
      source: B.Source
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check carefully on your yaml file, and make sure you have set the the full name of pipeline C for `source` node and select the right branch which contains the project. Make sure the project is under `master` branch.

Please do not forget to  add `- include` for master branch.

Use this:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: A
      source: A.source // the full name of the pipeline A
      trigger:
        branches:
         include:
          - master
    - pipeline: B
      source: B.Source // the full name of the pipeline B
      trigger:
        branches:
         include:
          - master
```

Then, when your run pipeline **A** and **B**, it will automatically trigger pipeline **C**.

I have tested in my side and it works well.

In my side, I have written like this:

```
resources:
 pipelines:
   - pipeline: me
     source: first_repository (2)
     trigger: 
      branches:
       include:
         - master
```

`first_repository (2)` is the name of the pipeline, then, I run `first_repository (2)`, also, you should refresh the page after `first_repository (2)` pipeline completed. And then you will see the below page.

[image]